# How to get index element?

Tags: javascript

How i can read index from element? example:

I have code:

```
<div class="a">
<span id="el">Yeah!</span>
<span class="span">1</span>
<span class="span">2MANO</span>
</div>
```

and javascript:
`var mySpan = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]; // it span id="el"` its ok,

but how i can read from this span index of this element

```
var span= document.getElementById("el"); // i should get index 0 but i cant do that
```

Comment: What do you mean by "index"? Position within its parent? Index relative to all other `span`s in the document? Something else entirely?

Comment: You can do something like, `var mySpans = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("span")); var index = mySpans.indexOf(document.getElementById("el"))`

Comment: index 0,1,2....

Comment: position within its parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you mean its position within its parent: To do that, count how many times `previousSibling` or `previousElementSibling` (depending on whether you want to count other kinds of nodes or just Elements) is not `null`:

Counting all node types:

```js
function getIndex(node) {
  var index = 0;
  while (node.previousSibling) {
    node = node.previousSibling;
    ++index;
  }
  return index;
}
console.log(getIndex(document.getElementById("el")));  // 0
console.log(getIndex(document.getElementById("el2"))); // 5, counts text nodes
```

```html
<div class="a">
<span id="el">Yeah!</span>
<span class="span">1</span>
<span class="span" id="el2">2MANO</span>
</div>
```

Counting only elements:

```js
function getElementIndex(node) {
  var index = 0;
  while (node.previousElementSibling) {
    node = node.previousElementSibling;
    ++index;
  }
  return index;
}
console.log(getElementIndex(document.getElementById("el")));  // 0
console.log(getElementIndex(document.getElementById("el2"))); // 2, counts only elements
```

```html
<div class="a">
<span id="el">Yeah!</span>
<span class="span">1</span>
<span class="span" id="el2">2MANO</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to if you are getting the element by `getElementById`. You would need to reference the parent and get the index of it via the parents children:

```js
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].children );
var span = document.getElementById('el');
var index = nodes.indexOf(span);
console.log(index); // 0
var span = document.getElementById('el2');
var index = nodes.indexOf(span);
console.log(index); // 1
```

```html
<div class="a">
<span id="el">Yeah!</span>
<span id="el2">Yeah!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can totally do this without referencing the parent at all.

Comment: Intriguing, perhaps you could provide an answer? I assumed there would be several methods for this, just unsure of them all.

Comment: I saw. A little more complex but I like it.

Comment: Well, only more complex if you ignore the complexity hidden in `Array.from` and `Array#indexOf`... :-) (But managing complexity with abstractions is a Good Thing™, so :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You can look at parent node and it's children (using ES6 syntax):

```
const span = document.getElementById("el");
const idx = [...span.parentNode.children].findIndex(n => n === span);
```

Here is alternative in ES5:

```
idx = Array.prototype.slice.call(span.parentNode.children)
  .reduce(function(result, node, i) {
    return node === span ? i : result;
  }, -1);
```